# Comparing client time on the server

Tags: node.js, datetime, timezone

If I have a string of the following format on the server, which could be in any timezone:

```
var timeString = 2014-05-24T14:00:00.000Z
```

What is the best way to to compare the hour represented by the string with the hour that a client may pass in as part of a GET request (Node.js)?

I need help because the date on the server and the date received from the client may be in Daylight Savings time, or in different timezones.

I tried passing in the client time as the number of milliseconds since Unix epoch:

```
var clientTime = new Date(parseInt(req.query.localTime));
var serverTime = new Date(timeString);
if (serverTime.getUTCHours() == clientTime.getUTCHours()) {
    // the hours match
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out moment.js, it makes date parsing stupid easy and has a companion library for dealing with timezone conversion (but not usually needed). There is a section in their documentation that explains dealing with UTC vs local and how to convert back and forth.

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/

```
var moment = require('moment')
var timeString = '2014-11-14T00:06:34.000Z'
var epochTime = 1415923594000

var serverTime = moment(timeString).utc()
var clientTime = moment(epochTime).utc()


console.log(serverTime.hour());
console.log(clientTime.hour())
```

Comment: What if I'm unsure which timezone the server and client are in? Will I have to worry about converting?

Comment: Unix time is always in UTC. The date time string you have as an example is in UTC, it is in ISO 8601 format with no time zone specified. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators